# Can't distribute a build with Server via Xcode Bot (certificate error with parent app)

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I have an Xcode Server set up that was working before I had to renew my distribution certificate. I renewed my certificate and edited all of my provisioning profiles so that they were Active again. Since doing this, I have not been able to successfully integrate an Xcode Bot so that a build can be distributed from the server. I get the following error every time...

```
Error error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.
```

I am able to successfully complete an archive locally from Xcode, just not on the build machine using a bot.

I've tried the following (all were suggestions from these forums or on Stack Overflow)...

- Removed expired certificates from Keychain
- Set up my certificate and key in Keychain on the build machine.
- Made sure Code Signing was using the Distribution certificate.
- Made sure the scheme is using Release for archives.
- Tried w/ and w/o Bitcode enabled (I have a watch extension).
- Explicitly selected the Code Signing Identity for each target for the Distribution Certificate.
- Explicitly selected the provisioning profile for each target.
- Signed out of my account in Xcode, logged back in and redownloaded all of the profiles.

One thing I haven't tried, and am hesitant to do so, is to delete all of my profiles and let Xcode regenerate them. I'm not absolutly sure that this would fix the issue, so I'm hoping to avoid this if possible (all of my profiles appear as Active).

Any ideas on how to resolve this? And thoughts on what could be causing this? Seriously, anything would help so I can figure this out and move on!

I'm happy to provide any other information that is needed to get this working!

Running Xcode 7.2 and Server 5.0.15.

Comment: Are you sure all the code signing settings are correct in both the Watch App and the main app?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after updating my distribution certificate. What worked for me was deleting all the provisioning profiles from the server. **These are different than the ones xcode uses.** They can be found at:

```
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles
```

You need root access to open this folder. I deleted all the provisioning profiles from there and then I went to the Server app and opened the xcode tab signed out and back into the Developer Team and then restarted xcode.

The server app should redownload the provision profiles to the same path above.

Hope this helps.